# NSDistributedNotificationCenter notification failed?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to post a notification in NSDistribtedNotificationCenter but I get these messages in console:

3/22/11 10:26:53 PM AIM[138]    *** Attempt to post a distributed notification (AIMIncomingMessages) with a non-dictionary userInfo (or one which is not a valid property list) ignored.

What does this mean?

EDIT: Here's the code:

```
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"AIMIncomingMessages"
                                                               object:nil
                                                             userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                       @"Event Source", [NSNumber numberWithInt:3],
                                                                       @"Message:", [arg2 attributedString],
                                                                       @"Username:", [arg3 name],
                                                                       @"Timestamp:", [NSDate date],
                                                                       nil]
                                                   deliverImmediately: YES];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means just what it says - When you created the notification with +notificationWithName:object:userInfo:, what you passed for the third argument (userInfo) wasn't a dictionary or other property list type, so the notification is being ignored. If you add the code you're using to create the notification to your question, I (or someone) can give you more detailed advice about exactly what's wrong with it.

(Edit) Okay, now that you've added the code: You've listed your objects and keys backwards when you create the dictionary. It needs to be the other way around, i.e. value, key, value, key instead of key, value, key, value.